# Multiplication with a variable in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, multiplication, exponent

OK guys I need this for my lab assignment. In a part of the project, I have to do this:

M*(2^E) where m is M2 M1 M0 3-bit number and e is E1 E0 2 bit number

I know that we add zeros to the end of the number while multiplying with 2 but the number 'E' is not constant.

I just want to know the way to do that

Language: VHDL
* I am not allowed to use 'behavioral' architecture

Thank you!

Comment: Think of what `2^E` actually does... there is a VHDL operator/function that implements this even for variable (non-constant) values.

Comment: As 'behavioral' is prohibited, and I am not sure this operator is allowed, this can be achieved by a simple lookup table since there is only 5 input bits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't give you a full solution, as it would defeat the purpose of the lab...

You know that you add a zero to the end of the number when multiplying by 2, I'm sure you can also figure out how many zeros to add as E1E0 goes from 0 to 3. Since there is only 4 cases, it would be easy to simply list all the cases:

```
with e select
    output <= "000" & m when "00",
              something when "01",
              something when "10",
              something when others;
```

You may or may not have seen this syntax in your classes. This goes in your architecture body, outside of a process. Inside a process, you would use a *case* statement instead.